# IntelliJ Plugin Development: insert new code after all fields within a class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I'm working a plugin that generates method within a class.

The problem is that the code I generate gets inserted randomly between other fields and methods. EG. I have 4 fields and my method gets inserted between the second and the third field breaking the field section in two parts.

**Question:** How to insert the new code **after** fields section?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
MyMembersHandlerBase extends GenerateMembersHandlerBase {

    @Override
    protected List<? extends GenerationInfo> generateMemberPrototypes(
            PsiClass psiClass, ClassMember[] members) {
        PsiMethod method1 = // method generation logic
        PsiMethod method2 = // ...

        return asList(
                new PsiGenerationInfo(method1),
                new PsiGenerationInfo(method2),
                ...
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected ClassMember[] getAllOriginalMembers(PsiClass psiClass) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Update:** I've found ["Rearrange Code"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/rearranging-code-using-arrangement-rules.html#d215466e53) feature in UI. Probably invoking it programmatically would solve my problem, but I haven't found so far how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action can be called this way:

```
Editor editor = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).getSelectedTextEditor();
ActionManager actionManager = ActionManager.getInstance();
AnAction rearrangeAction = actionManager.getAction("RearrangeCode");
DataContext dataContext = DataManager.getInstance()
        .getDataContext(editor.getContentComponent());
Presentation presentation = rearrangeAction.getTemplatePresentation();
rearrangeAction.actionPerformed(
        AnActionEvent.createFromDataContext("", presentation, dataContext)
);
```

But IMHO more correct is to search AST for first method or end of declaration and insert method in right place.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try tomorrow. But how exactly can I insert the method in right place? The trick is that I only return the generated methods from ‘generateMemberPrototypes’ and the platform inserts the methods for me. I used IntelliJ embedded constructor generator as an example - it gets inserted properly, but I haven’t managed to understand what makes it doing that.

Comment: Didn't use GenerateMembersHandlerBase. But with Document.insertString() you can insert anything at any offset.